# Heat transfer in glass top ranges

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-life, thermal-radiation, heat-conduction

1. The "glass" in glass top ranges apparently has quite low heat
   conductivity as areas just a short distance from the heating element
   don't get so hot - especially compared to a metal surface which has
   excellent heat conductivity.
2. The glass does not get red-hot.
3. Presume the glass top is essentially transparent to infrared?
4. Conclusion: the dominant heat transfer mechanism is radiation.

Questions:

- Is #3 above true?
- Is #4 above true?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the primary mechanism of heat transfer to the cooking utensils on a glass ceramic cook top is infrared radiation from the hot metal coil just below the surface. The low thermal conductivity of glass ceramic helps keep the conductive heating of the glass localized below the utensil.

Hope this helps